# Laravel server memory is increasing constantly

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got a Laravel application running with about 800-1.000 concurrent users (10.000 users overall). The main time frame of use is from 8 am to 6 pm. However, the **server's memory is increasing constantly** (see attachment) and reaches its high at about 10 pm (about 100 concurrent users). 
I assume that query logging causes the constant increase of memory. I tried to stop it by including `DB::disableQueryLog();` into the boot function in the *AppServiceProvider.php*. However, this doesn't seem to stop query logging. How could I fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you running any queue workers or constantly looping some code? I notice the day previous usage didn't go as high - did something get deployed today?

Comment: This is because of easter holidays that ended yesterday so the traffic is back to normal right now.